# Install one package without checking all requirements with composer

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

I have a composer.json like this:

```
{
"require": {
    "symfony/yaml" : "dev-master",
    "symfony/console" : "dev-master",
    "ebuildy/ebuildy" : "dev-master",
    "keboola/php-encryption": "dev-master",
    "pear-pear.php.net/mail_mime" : "*",
    "pear-pear.php.net/http_request2" : "*",
    "pear-pear.php.net/mail_mimedecode" : "*",
    "microsoft/windowsazure": "*",
    "rollbar/rollbar": "dev-master",
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*",
    "happyr/linkedin-api-client": "dev-master",
    "zircote/swagger-php" : "dev-master",
    "google/apiclient" : "dev-master"
},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
           "bizlunch": "src/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Just added "google/apiclient", I want to install this new package without checking other packages requirements (because on my dev machine "keboola/php-encryption" complains about crypt ext missing and other stuff).

What is the right command? Tried already update PACKAGE, but this fails:

```
$root: php composer.phar update google/apiclient       
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
- keboola/php-encryption dev-master requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to ignore the specifics of your local system, you can use `--ignore-platform-reqs` flag. Keep in mind that it **may result in unusable lockfile in production**.

Let's show it on imaginary scenario:

- you don't have `ext-crypt` locally and neither in production.
- there is package `cryptX` that

  - in `cryptX:1.0` uses `lib-crypt-polyfill` (that does what `ext-crypt` does using PHP code)
  - but in `cryptX:2.0` they changed the dependency to `ext-crypt`.

Now if you were to install it normally, you'd get version 1 (which is the only one meeting the dependencies). But with `--ignore-platform-reqs` it just works as if whatever it wants is available in your system. So it happily installs version 2, which does not work on you machine, but what's more it won't work on you production server neither.

Answer (score 0):

As easy as

```
php composer.phar update google/apiclient
```

or you can specify several individual packages as

```
php composer.phar update google/apiclient zircote/swagger-php rollbar/rollbar
```

Comment: Not working, this is what I tried first. I am posting error response. Thanks.

Comment: If that isn't working, then perhaps you should file a bug report..... because that is the officially documented method

Answer (score 0):

Maybe PHP extension mcrypt isn't installed on your machine. See how to install it here http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.setup.php

In an Ubuntu machine run :

apt-get install php5-mcrypt

php5enmod mcrypt

service apache2 restart